# React native: Horizontal FlatList flickers it's container background

Tags: react-native

When scrolling fast from RTL on a horizontal flatlist the container of flatlist background is shown for a quick instance on Android device. Is there a way to prevent this behavior?

You can see the example to reproduce issue at snack https://snack.expo.dev/@danro/flatlist-selectable

To reproduce error select android device and scroll to second/third item then quickly scroll to first item and you will observe the red background I set on parent container.